# How to limit the length of each line in a text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file of following type-

`eng Firstly, in the course of the last few decades the national 
 eng Secondly, the national courts will be empowered to implement
 eng However, I am convinced of the fact that the White Paper has put us on 
 the right path.`

I want to restrict the length of each line upto (say) 9 words.
I tried of using python's read_line method but it specifies the size of the line only.I am unable to find any other suitable method. How to do it ?

Sample Output-

```
eng Firstly, in the course of the last few
eng Secondly, the national courts will be empowered to
eng However, I am convinced of the fact that
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the first n words of a string as a string:

```
def first_n_words(s, n):
    return ' '.join(s.split()[:n])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of each word like so:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.rstrip('\n').split())
```

Now limit each line to 9 by using slicing which truncated automatically:

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(' '.join(line[:9]))
        f.write('\n')
```